# How to interchange colors of the bar graphs dynamically using coreplot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, core-plot

I tried to implement the stacked bars provided as example in below mentioned link.

Every time when i run this example app, the maximum value for the plot is always taken by red color. This is the log i got.

```
2014-02-13 13:04:18.347 CorePlotBarChartExample[3666:70b] {
"2012-05-01" =     {
    "Plot 1" = 7;
    "Plot 2" = 7;
};
"2012-05-02" =     {
    "Plot 1" = 5;
    "Plot 2" = 6;
};
"2012-05-03" =     {
    "Plot 1" = 7;
    "Plot 2" = 9;
};
**"2012-05-04"** =     {
    **"Plot 1" = 10;**
    **"Plot 2" = 4;**
};
**"2012-05-05" =     {
    "Plot 1" = 4;
    "Plot 2" = 10;**
};
"2012-05-06" =     {
    "Plot 1" = 6;
    "Plot 2" = 1;
};
"2012-05-07" =     {
    "Plot 1" = 8;
    "Plot 2" = 6;
};
```

}

For date **2012-05-04**  Plot 1 value is 10 which is taken by red color. 
For date **2012-05-05**  Plot 2 value is 10 which is also taken by red color.[I was expecting blue color]

I want to interchange colors i.e 
For date 2012-05-04  Plot 1 value is 10.I should give red color.
For date 2012-05-05  Plot 2 value is 10.I should give blue color.

This is the link for the image runned in simulator:
Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhQaB.png

Link for stacked bars example: https://github.com/gilthonweapps/CorePlotBarChartExample

Also can anyone provide me the best links/tutorials, for stacked bars using core plot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegate method:

```
-(CPTFill *)barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

It gives you a bar plot and index so you can use it to find out the data from datasource and if it match your criteria you can set up the right colour.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each plot has a unique `identifier`. Check it in the datasource and make sure you're returning values for the correct plot.